# Visual Basic Issue getting listbox to populate from text file

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

I am stuck and have tried re-writing my code multiple times and cannot figure out a solution.  The application has a text file containing items and prices in a sequential access file.  The app should display the price corresponding with the item when it is selected from the list box.  Each line in the text file contains the item's number followed by a comma and then the price.

I need to define a structure named item.  The structure has 2 member variables, a string to store the item number and a decimal storing the price.  I also need to declare a class level array with 5 item structure variables.  The load even should read the items and prices and store this info in the class-level array.  Then it should add the item numbers to the list box.

This is what I have so far but nothing is working.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain
    'declare structure with 2 member variables
    Structure Item
        Public strItemNum As String
        Public decPrice As Decimal
    End Structure

    'declare array for 5 item structure variables
    Private items(4) As Item

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'declare variables
        Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
        Dim strLineofText As String
        Dim intSub As Integer

        'check if the file exists
        If IO.File.Exists("ItemInfo.txt") Then
            'open the file
            inFile = IO.File.OpenText("ItemInfo.txt")
            'read the file
            Do Until inFile.Peek = -1 OrElse
                intSub = items.Length
                strLineofText = inFile.ReadLine.Trim
                'add item to list box
                lstNumbers.Items.Add(items(intSub).strItemNum)
            Loop
            'close the file
            inFile.Close()

        Else
        MessageBox.Show("Can't find the ItemInfo.txtfile",
                       "Kensington Industries",
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstNumbers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstNumbers.SelectedIndexChanged
        lblPrice.Text = items(lstNumbers.SelectedIndex).decPrice.ToString("C2")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You've forgotten to increment `intSub`.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/27080237/1070452

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to change the name of Structure. Item can be used in another references.

Try to change the name to itemstr (for example)

```
     Do Until inFile.Peek = -1 OrElse
        intSub = items.Length
        strLineofText = inFile.ReadLine.Trim
        'add item to list box
        Dim arr As String() = str.Split(","C)
        Dim valitem As New itemstr()
        valitem.text = arr(0)
        valitem.value = Convert.ToDecimal(arr(1))
        lstNumbers.Items.Add(valitem)
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  I ended up starting over again and trying something different that works finally!

Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain
    'declare structure
    Structure Item
        Public strItemNum As String
        Public decPrice As Decimal
    End Structure

```
'declare class level array
Public itemList(4) As Item

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'declare variables
    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
    Dim strLineOfText As String
    Dim decPrice As Decimal
    Dim strInfo(4, 1) As String

    'check to see if the file exists
    If IO.File.Exists("ItemInfo.txt") Then
        'open the file
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("ItemInfo.txt")

        For intRow As Integer = 0 To strInfo.GetUpperBound(0)
            'read the line
            strLineOfText = inFile.ReadLine

            'assign substring from comma to first coloumn
            strInfo(intRow, 0) = strLineOfText.Substring(0, strLineOfText.IndexOf(","))

            Dim intSep As Integer = strLineOfText.IndexOf(",") + 1

            'assign substring after comma to 2nd column
            strInfo(intRow, 1) = strLineOfText.Substring(intSep)

            'assign first column value to strItemNum variable
            itemList(intRow).strItemNum = (strInfo(intRow, 0))

            Decimal.TryParse(strInfo(intRow, 1), decPrice)

            'assign 2nd columnn value to decPrice variable
            itemList(intRow).decPrice = decPrice


            'add item to listbox
            lstNumbers.Items.Add(itemList(intRow).strItemNum)
        Next intRow

        'clost the file
        inFile.Close()

    Else
        'error message if file cannot be found
        MessageBox.Show("Can't find the ItemInfo.txtfile",
                       "Kensington Industries",
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lstNumbers_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lstNumbers.SelectedIndexChanged
    'display the price 
    lblPrice.Text = itemList(lstNumbers.SelectedIndex).decPrice.ToString("C2")
End Sub
```

End Class